# Should I confirm/verify an existing Debian bug?

Tags: linux, debian, bugs

I am currently experiencing similar issues as reported in [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729081) on my Debian laptop (similar symptoms, different software). I've read the [documentation](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting) on bug reporting but I'm not sure what is considered best practice in this situation.

Obviously I shouldn't create an new report if one already exists for this bug, but is it good practice to send a "me too" message to confirm that the bug actually exists, or will that just create unnecessary clutter?

If so, should I send a simple email to `<number>@bugs.debian.org` describing my basic setup, or is more required?

Answer (score 2):

You do not provide enough information to answer your question fully.

In general, you should open a new bug report if you are not quite sure that your bug is the *same* as the reported (same behaviour, same software/hardware, same log messages, ....).

If you are not sure, you can add a note to your new bug report with a reference to the existing bug report that you think is related. The package maintainers can easily merge reports if needed (splitting reports is much more difficult).

If a bug occurs in several programs, there could be an underlying bug. But especially with hardware/driver-related bugs, there can be a lot of different reasons leading to similar behaviour (like not working suspend or brightness control).

Appending a message to an existing bug report makes only sense if you can add some new relevant information or if want to offer your help (often you can do this already without special knowledge). "Me too"-only-messages should be avoided. This is not the case for bugs tagged `unreproducible`, here the information that someone else can reproduce them is valuable.

In general, package maintainer are thankful for each bug report or additional information to an existing bug. But flooding them with very similar reports or reports with bad quality should be avoided.